Store nested classes in multiples columns using entity framework
I have my class Character which have WorldPosition class which have two Vector2int (Map and Cell). Also a World property that is a combination of Map and Cell. How can I store it in the database as 2 (X, Y) or 4 columns (MapX, MapY, CellX, CellY) in the Characters table?
My classes:
public class Character : IMessageSerializable
{
    //other members...
    public WorldPosition Position;
}

public class WorldPosition : IMessageSerializable
{
    private Vector2Int _map;
    private Vector2Int _cell;
    private Vector2Int _world;

    // Getter setter
    public Vector2Int Map { get => _map; set { _map = value; UpdateWorld(); } }
    public Vector2Int Cell
    {
        get => _cell;
        set
        {
            _cell = value;
            AdjustToMapBoundaries();
            UpdateWorld();
        }
    }
    public Vector2Int World { get => _world; set { _world = value; UpdateMapAndCell(); } }
}

The best try I had was using fluent APi:
modelBuilder.Entity<Character>().ComplexProperty(c => c.Map, b =>
{
    b.Property(p => p.x).HasColumnName("MapX");
    b.Property(p => p.y).HasColumnName("MapY");
});
modelBuilder.Entity<Character>().ComplexProperty(c => c.Cell, b =>
{
    b.Property(p => p.x).HasColumnName("CellX");
    b.Property(p => p.y).HasColumnName("CellY");
});

// or

modelBuilder.Entity<Character>().ComplexProperty(c => c.Position, b =>
{
    b.Property(p => p.World.x).HasColumnName("X");
    b.Property(p => p.World.y).HasColumnName("Y");
});

I also tried to use ValueConverter, but none is working. Can someone help me? I don't want to create a separate table for the positions.
